# replace certain strings in a file

Tags: python, string, file

I have a text file, I need to replace it with some strings.I need to write it to the file.
**Problem**
How should I write the replaced strings over the file to another file/same file,without changing the indentation and spacing?

My code:

```
a='hi'
b='hello'
with open('out2','r') as f:
 if 'HI' in f:
    m = re.sub(r'HI', a)
 if 'HELLO' in f:
    m = re.sub(r'HELLO', b)
out2.close()
```

please help me to complete my code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read/write file to the same file, you need to open the file with `r+` mode.

string replacement should be done against string, not the file. Read the file content and replace against the string, and write the replaced string back.

```
with open('out2', 'r+') as f:
    content = f.read()
    content = re.sub('HI', 'hi', content)
    content = re.sub('HELLO', 'hello', content)
    f.seek(0)  # Reset file position to the beginning of the file
    f.write(content)
    f.truncate()  # <---- If the replacement string is shorter than the original one,
                  #       You need this. Otherwise, there will be remaining of
                  #         content before the replacement.
```

BTW, for the given strings, you don't need to use regular expression. [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) is enough.

```
content = content.replace('Hi', 'hi')
content = content.replace('HELLO', 'hello')
```

Comment: if I had a='hi',could I do `content = re.sub('HI', a, content)`

Comment: @user3631292, Yes, you can. Or you can use `str.replace`: `content = content.replace('HI', a)`

Comment: @user3631292, If you mean to downcase uppercase `hi`: `content = content.replace(a.upper(), a)`

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of `Regex` for this. You can simply do it as:

```
with open('out2','r') as f:
  with open('outFile','w') as fp:  
    for line in f:
      line=line.replace('HI','hi')
      line=line.replace('HELLO','hello')
      fp.write(line)
```